# Adding multiple --module-path with JLink

Tags: java, jlink

I was following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jlink) tutorial to create a runtime image using JLink. When I reached this part

```bash
jlink --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%\jmods";out
  --add-modules jlinkModule
  --output customjre
```

The semicolon seperated commands in Windows terminal (PowerShell). So it says:

```bash
Error: --output must be specified
Usage: jlink <options> --module-path <modulepath> --add-modules <module>[,<module>...]
Use --help for a list of possible options
out: The term 'out' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

So I tried using comma, but not working. I tried this:
`jlink --module-path 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\jmods\' --module-path out --add-modules jlinkModule --output customjre`

And the file created but I think I did it wrong. What should I two to add multiple --module-path. Also I want to include `com.fasterxml.Jackson` but I don't know how to add this in JLink.

I searched a lot and found some solutions for other external libraries but I couldn't do this with Jackson. I appreciate any answers.

Comment: This is a PowerShell thing. Surround the entire thing in quotes: `--module-path "<path>;<path>"`.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok

---

jlink --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%/jmods;./out" --add-modules jlinkModule --output customjre

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).